# How to pass List<object> to another activity in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android-intent, xamarin.android, pass-data

I have List and I want to pass it to another activity
when I Serialize it using JsonConvert.serialize in the first activity and deserialize it on the other one, It works only when I am logging it to console, but when I set it as a value it gives me an error that says the value is null.

//activity one
`string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(VideosList); Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(HomeActivity)); intent.PutExtra("media", jsonData); StartActivity(intent);`

//activity two
`string jsonData2 = Intent.GetStringExtra("media"); // i can log it  List<Video> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Video>>(jsonData2); here give me null`

Answer (score 0):

At first, I think the data type shouldn't be declared as the string. So you can try to use the following code.

```
intent.PutExtra("media", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(VideosList)); 
StartActivity(intent);
```

And use it in the other activity:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Video>>(Intent.GetStringExtra("media"));
```

If it doesn't work, you may need to implement the Parcelable interface by your self.

Comment: putting this Code inside OnStart() Method was the solution